# Parcel java android

Tags: android, java

Недавно наткнулся на такое понятие, как Parcel. Всё, что удалось понять, что это контейнер для передачи данных. Объясните, если не сложно, для чего он применяется, часто ли используется. Вообще, важен ли он, чтобы выделять под него время для изучения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используется, как правило, для передачи сложных объектов( пользовательских классов ) между частями приложения, между активностями; для сохранения и последующего "разворота" данных.

Думаю, нет смысла перепечатывать офф.доки, если у вас с английским более-менее все в порядке, то прошу сюда: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

Answer (score 2):

`Parcel` в багаже Android девелопера это **must know** - это один из немногих инструментов для передачи данных между `Activity`.

По сути это способ IPC (Inter-process communication) через специфическую сериализацию/десериализацию данных (Google предпочитает термин `flatten/unflatten`), при этом в отличие от стандартного Java `Serializable` - здесь требуется реализация интерфейса `Parcelable`, в котором должны быть реализованы методы записи в `Parcel` (*parcel* к слову переводится как *посылка*) и чтения из `Parcel`. Утверждается, что механизм IPC через `Parcelable` гораздо эффективнее чем через Java сериализацию или обмен через персистентный набор данных типа БД.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ почти... но я бы сказал, что это android-вский Externalizable, потому нечего страшного если юзаеться обычный Serializable

Comment: @Gorets `Parcelable` пошире `Serializable`, любой `Serializable` можно представить в виде `Parcelable`, но не наоборот

Comment: Расшифруйте, пожалуйста, где сохраняется parcel?